# Runtime generated controls disabled for Async Postback asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, partial-postback

I want to create at runtime some items that must not hit the "async postback".

Actually I have a button for each row in my grid view. This controls must not generate the partial postback but the complete postback ('cause the result must be the download of a report).

Actually I tried in 2 ways:

1. On page load

   - recursive search for every controls that is a Button and have the specified class
   - add the item to the ScriptManager via:

     ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(control);
   - this code is hitted the right number of time, but partial postback is still generated
2. On item generation

   - I add a "OnDataBinding" event to the button generation
   - in this event I do something like:

     var button = (Control)sender;

     ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(button);

Why isn't this working?

In both cases I hit the specific case and "register" the controls as "do full postback" so way do I get the partial one?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A button without postback or..?

Comment: A button that when is clicked create a FULL postback instead of a partial one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out a solution that works and that does not involve any particular code / overriding.

I was focussing on the single "automatically-generated" button but when I start thinking about areas and parents everything goes fine.

As solution I simply register the WHOLE GridView to the Script Manager, by this way, all the controller inside generates a full postback instead of a partial one.

In my Page_Load I have now:

```
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent().RegisterPostBackControl(grd_Reports);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by partial postback but I guess you are trying to do something on button click event which you want to occur after page load. There is a quick walkaround for this, on pageload event you can check which button was clicked.

```
if(IsPostBack){
    clickedButtonID=Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]; 
}
```